# Required Wordpress specific category posts display on static page with newer order at the top

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two different post categories ("Local" & "International") in WordPress and I have displayed the posts in my static page. Right now both categories post are coming on one page. Can I show only local posts in `local.php` and International posts in `International.php` page? Also another change please. Can I show newer posts at the top? Right now older post is at the top.

Following is my code.

```
<?php
  require('wp-blog-header.php');
?>

<?php
  $posts = get_posts('numberposts=10&order=ASC&orderby=post_title');
  foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>
    <?php echo "<h1>";the_date();echo "</h1>"; ?>
    <?php the_title(); ?>    
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
<?php
  endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: is local.php your custom file? or a template file

Comment: Local.php and International are my custom files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=10&order=DESC&category=[categoryID]&orderby=post_title');
```

in `local.php` respectively `International.php`. Notice that `order=DESC` instead of `order=ASC`, this reverses the post order. And be sure to use the appropriate categoryIDs. You find them in your Wordpress administration area.

Comment: Working :) Awesome Dude, Great Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming custom page as a page in yours custom plugin. you will need to load `wp-load.php` to use the WordPress function/loops to fetch the information.

you will need

```
require_once("../../../wp-load.php");    // ../../../ according to you file location

// now you can loop using get_posts 
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=10&category=CATEGORY_ID&order=DESC&');
// loop
```

If this is not in WordPress, you have to connect to MySQL and the fetch the information from tables with you SELECT query.